# Unable to identify filesystem of hard drive from old recorder

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

My family used to have a dvd player that would allow recording from our old video camera, it had a sata hard disk inside it which we removed after it broke a few years ago. I am trying to now restore the stored video camera data from it. I do not remember the brand, I think it was a Samsung, but I cannot be sure.

I started up a ubuntu on my desktop to try and access the disk, because Windows would not recognize it. To be sure I made a copy with ddrescue to a disk I still had.

`sfdisk -l` tells me the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000AAKX-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf9a7e03b

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        4 312581807 312581804 149.1G a5 FreeBSD
```

Which made me try mounting as netbsd and freebsd as referenced from this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275929/mount-freebsd-ufs-from-logical-partition-under-linux).

Because it stated the disk label is of type dos I even tried mounting it as `msdos` without success.

Additionaly I tried ext2 because `fsck -N /dev/sda1` returned the following:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext2 (1) -- /dev/sda1] fsck.ext2 /dev/sda1
```

But this was also did not work.

I'm trying to find out how I can possibly mount this partition, or potentially extract video fragments off of it, any input would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a Digital Forensic Toolbox, like http://www.sleuthkit.org to try to extract your data. See if there is a packaged `sleuthkit` with `apt-cache search sleuthkit`

Comment: What is the make/model of the device(s) that made these recordings?